# Bundle doesn't compile

Tags: npm, bigcommerce

Today I have got some issue after updating `Stencil` Command-Line Interface.
I have done this command `npm install -g bigcommerce/stencil-cli` and now and don't have opportunity to make any bundle.

When I run `stencil` bundle, in all of my theme, I receive this error:

```
  SCSS Parsing Started...                                                                                                                                                   
Template Parsing Started...                                                                                                                                               
Language Files Parsing Started...                                                                                                                                         
Building Theme Schema File...                                                                                                                                             
Generating Manifest Started...                                                                                                                                            
Theme custom task Started...                                                                                                                                              
ok -- Language Files Parsing Finished                                                                                                                                     
ok -- Manifest Generation Finished                                                                                                                                        
ok -- SCSS Parsing Finished                                                                                                                                               
ok -- Theme Schema Building Finished                                                                                                                                      

D:\...\stencil.conf.js:71                                                                                                                            
            throw err;                                                                                                                                                    
            ^                                                                                                                                                             
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'pace' in D:\...\assets\js\theme\global                                          
at D:\...\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:229:38                                                                                         at onDoneResolving (D:\...\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:29:20)                                                                
    at D:\...\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:85:20                                                                                  
    at D:\...\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:726:13                                                                                                 
    atD:\...\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16                                                                                                  
    at done (D:\...\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:241:17)                                                                                          
    at D:\...\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16                                                                                                  
    at D:\...\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:723:17                                                                                                 
    at D:\...\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:167:37                                                                                                 
    at D:\...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:24:19
```

Anyone know what I should improve? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this issue comment for a temporary fix: https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil/pull/861#issuecomment-256523133